# Unusual behavior with C++ vectors

Tags: c++, oop, vector

```
struct Base{
    int hp = 1000;
    virtual ~Base()
    {
        std::cout << "Base destructor\n";
    }
};

struct Child : Base {
    int hp = 100;
    virtual ~Child()
    {
        std::cout << "Child destructor\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Base*>vct;
    for(int x=0;x<25;x++)
    { 
        vct.push_back(new Child);
    }
    std::cout << vct[3]->hp;
    return 0;
}
```

I have written this program, which creates 25 objects of type Child, yet when run, both the destructors of the child and base class are called, which would imply that the 'new child' call would create an instance of both the child, and the base class. Why?

Furthermore, trying to access the int "hp" of any of the members of the vector, always returns 1000, not 100, which indicates that all the vector members are of type Base, not of type Child.
So in short, what do I need to do to 1. only create Child objects, not Base(even having the Base class as an abstract class still, somehow, seems to create objects of it) 2. Have all the members/elements of the vector to be of the child class, when the type of the vector is Base*

Comment: Are you sure the dtors are called in the code that you posted?

Comment: Because `Child` contains a `Base`. When you destroy a class (and the destuctor is `virtual` which it is in this code) , all base classes will be destroyed to make sure all of the destruction logic of the base classes is also respected. Otherwise the derived class would have to know enough about the base class to be able to repeat the effort. Not only is this a waste of code, the derived class cannot properly manage the `private` members of the base.

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly how C++ inheritance works.  Even if you didn't explicitly define a constructor, the parent class's default constructor still runs.  In this case, the default constructors are mostly a no-op save for the member initialization of `hp` in both.

Both `Child destructor` and `Base destructor` get printed because you declared your destructor (correctly) as virtual.  **However**, you aren't explicitly deleting any instance of objects you are allocating via `new`, so I'm not sure how you are seeing any print statements at all.

The `hp` in Child shadows the `hp` in Base, but member variables are not virtual.  So when you access `hp` via Base class pointer, you get the Base class member.  If you want to have the derived class access to `hp`, mark `hp` as protected in Base, and set in constructor in derived.  In you case, everything is a struct, so all members are already public.

```
struct Base{
    int hp = 1000;
    virtual ~Base()
    {
        std::cout << "Base destructor\n";
    }

};

struct Child : Base {
    Child()
    {
       hp = 100;  // Base constructor has already run, so we override here
    }

    virtual ~Child()
    {
        std::cout << "Child destructor\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Base*>vct;
    for(int x=0;x<25;x++)
    { 
        vct.push_back(new Child);
    }
    std::cout << vct[3]->hp;


    // let's delete explicitly and avoid the leak.
    for(int x=0;x<25;x++)
    { 
        delete vec[x];
        vec[x] = nullptr; // not necessary, but is a good practice
    }

    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: Same question for you. Why would dtors to `Base` or `Child` be called in your current main()?

Comment: In the code sample you posted, that can't happen.  The allocated instance will leak since there's not an explicit delete call for the corresponding `new` calls of `Child`

Comment: I did not post any code. Best to fix your memory leak in the answer as this is likely to be the accepted solution.

Comment: Oops.  You are correct. There's no destructor being run in the OPs post.  Fixed.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the confusion about object deletion, I had fixed originally that memory leak, but decided to leave it out to make my code example shorter and thus easier to read (as object deletion isn't technically necessary), didn't realize such an act may cause confusion. Also, why does adding the "int hp;" declaration to the Child struct cause the Child objects to have a hp value of 1000, EVEN when defining the value of hp in the constructor?